# Why is my React component staying a step behind?

Tags: reactjs

In my component, I have

```
  componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log('here we roll', prevProps, prevState);
    if(this.props.searchQuery.length > 0 && prevProps.searchQuery != prevState.value) {
      this.setState({value: this.props.searchQuery})
    }
  }
```

So when the parent component passes down the prop that becomes `searchQuery`, the `value` of the current `state` is a step behind:

Here's what I see:

```
here we roll

Object {placeholder: "Search all the Vidys", autoSearch: true, searchQuery: "", showLogo: false}

Object {value: "a", hints: Array[0], isMobile: true, placeholder: "Type Something...", selectedSearch: false…}
```

So why is it that the value is `a` of the previous state and the `prop` is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happening because you are comparing props before rendering with state before rendering and not the current props with the current state which have already been rendered.

You should ideally use `componentWillReceiveProps` to propagate props to state:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState) {
    if(nextProps.searchQuery != this.state.value) {
      this.setState({value: nextProps.searchQuery})
    }
  }
```